# MySQL: adding and multiplying on different tables

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, one contains data like this:

```
link_id | counted
=================
1--------| 1
==================
2------- | 0
==================
3 -------| 1
===================
```

I want to select those that are counted = 1, and then with the ids here I want to go to the table link (whose ids are in the link_id table above), and multiply each by its corresponding factor:

```
id | factor
===========
1  |  0.3
============
2  |  0.1
===========
3  |  0.5
==========
```

So for the values above it would be:

counted = 1 in first table, 1 and 3.
Now,

```
1*0.3 + 3*.5 = 0.3+1.5 = 1.8
```

How can I do this with a MySQL query?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(first_table.link_id * second_table.factor) as ANSWER
FROM   first_table
LEFT JOIN second_table on first_table.link_id = second_table.id
WHERE  first_table.counted = 1
```