# Mysql query that multiplies values returns double

Tags: mysql

I am trying to take unit sales by week from one table and multiply by pricing in another table and get the results by product.  I used [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6946636/mysql-adding-and-multiplying-on-different-tables).  The results are exactly double what they should be.

The query looks like:

```
SELECT product, week, SUM(units * price) AS revenue
FROM weekly_sales
JOIN pricing ON
    weekly_sales.product = pricing.product
GROUP BY product, week;
```

I have tried a few things like using DISTINCT.  Originally was doing a second join to get catalog info, but removed that to be sure that wasn't the issue.  I also used WHERE week = current.week to see if I could get it to work for just one week, but same issue.  Thanks!

weekly_sales looks like:

```
product    | units    | week
B001       |     5    | 41
B001       |     2    | 42
B002       |     3    | 41
B002       |     8    | 42
```

pricing table looks like:

```
product | current_price | week
B001    |     6.99      | 41
B002    |     8.99      | 41
```

results look like:

```
product | week | revenue
B001    |  42  | 69.9
B001    |  41  | 27.96
B002    |  42  | 53.94
```

Comment: Can you also show a sample of the data, and the output you're getting from the query, if run against that sample data set.

Comment: @Spudley added some samples.  The revenue values are correct but instead of price x units, it is price x units x 2.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Try to look at your data without grouping. The lines may have duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should add one more condition in join as follows:

```
SELECT product, week, (units * price) AS revenue
FROM weekly_sales
JOIN pricing ON
    weekly_sales.product = pricing.product
and weekly_sales.week = pricing.week
GROUP BY 1, 2;
```

[Click here for DEMO](http://rextester.com/TIWWN32289)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Do you have multiple rows for any of the `(product,week)` pair in your `weekly_sales` table? If No, then there is no need of sum().

Comment: Please check the DEMO as well.

Comment: It is still double.  Also, we don't update pricing weekly.  If I used your suggestion, would I need pricing weekly?  I tried putting in pricing values in for each week to check and it is still double, though.

Comment: If you want pricing for each week then there should be row for each product for each week I guess no matter which solution you are using.

Comment: Also, can you tell me the difference between the sample data I used in demo and the actual data? coz its working properly for the sample data. Also, are you doing any other join in this query? Coz that may create duplication,too.

Comment: I have had the hardest time with this and could not figure out what was wrong.  The problem was GROUP BY and SUM.  If I used SUM without GROUP BY, it only returned one line.  So the correction would have been (units * price) without SUM.  If you correct your answer, I will set it as the correct one.